# Using Python results in Webpage or other applications - Data Science

Tags: python, web

I created some python scripts that use python ML libraries to make some predictions and data analysis from CSV files which I create manually.

I need to use the results data of python scripts in my webpage (MVC 5 WebServer and MS-SQL DB), in other words I want to automate the process.

I currently know about SQL Server external scripts, but for me that is not possible because I dont have the right version.

Can someone show me some available approaches  which I can follow to integrate the python results in my web page (or DB).

Comment: python dash is a good tool to visualize and create results. If not, you can read the data from a database run ml algorithm save as a model. Use this model, for predictions through a web application utilizing flask, javascript

Comment: @coldy, That means I have to create new web app I think.
I have the website already in production, Im just asking for some ways to retrieve the python generated results into the Db or WepPage by any library or something.
Anyway thanks for the recommandation.

Comment: you could create http requests like get, post etc.. where the ml part is done and your website could make use of some calls to such routes, right?

Answer (score 1):

The code example below takes some CSV, puts it into `pandas` dataframe, creates an `SQLite` database, runs a SQL query on this table, and puts the output into a `pandas` dataframe again. I think you could modify the SQL bit to adopt this to your use case. No?

```
import pandas as pd

import sqlite3 as db

path = 'path/to/some.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path)

conn = db.connect('my_solution.db')

df.to_sql('table_from_df', conn, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)

sql_query = '''
    select
        userid,
        group_concat(txt, ' ') as txt
    from table_from_df
    group by 1
    order by 1
'''

out_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn)

out_df

conn.close()
```

Comment: My goal is to use the pandas generated result into DB, 
If your query:
df.to_sql('tbl', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False) 
overwrites the Sql Table, that will be enough for me. 
Is it so?